# How do you create and empty linked list node in python?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

According to leetcode this is the definition of a linked list

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
```

How do you create a single node that when called outputs

```
[]
```

instead of

```
[0]
```

In the merge two linked lists if we pass two empty nodes then the output is also an empty node, the question is how do you make an empty `ListNode` that has a value other than `0` or `None`

Comment: How does the code you're showing there output `[0]`?

Comment: Since the default value is for `val` is `0` it outputs `0`

Comment: Why not use self.next=None, self.val=None for __init__ without other parameters except self

Comment: Did you try setting the `val` to `''`?

Comment: Please add the specific code challenge and your code and how it is a problem with that code to specify an empty list (which would be `None`).

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It is not clear why you expect the output to be a list

Comment: Setting the default val to '' would cause worse problems because now val can be a string or int.  Just default it to None.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as you but I just figured it out. All you have to do is return None and Leetcode will accept it. I tested it on Leetcode problem 23, Merge k Sorted Lists.

Comment: Right answer, I tested it with problem "[1171. Remove Zero Sum Consecutive Nodes from Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-zero-sum-consecutive-nodes-from-linked-list/description/)"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Empty Linked List and assuming head is given.

```
curr = head
curr.next = None
curr = curr.next
```

Answer (score 0):

LeetCode lets you specify linked lists using Python list notation for executing tests in the browser. This is *not* how the linked list is actually represented in memory; LeetCode runs code on their backend to take the list you input as a test case and turn it into a linked list.

If you're trying to test your code locally and want to represent an empty linked list, use `None` rather than `[]`. A linked list with one node can be declared as follows:

```py
singleton_linked_list = ListNode(5) # Creates a new linked list with one node.
```

Comment: I used `None` but i get a wrong answer

Comment: Are you running things locally? Can you edit your driver code into the original question?

Comment: By locally i assume you mean on my pc which is not what i am doing i am running the code in the browser

Comment: Use `[]` to represent an empty linked list in the browser. A singleton linked list can be represented as a list with one element.

Comment: this does not work

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is that it does not match the expected value

Comment: That suggests an issue with your solution to the problem. The syntax for the input case is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following while solving your problem in LeetCode:

```
if not lists:
   return None
if len(lists) == 1:
   return lists[0]
```

Thus, whenever there is input like `[]` or `[[]]`, so after execution LeetCode compiler will return an empty List with None.